# Static code visualization tool for any language?

Tags: static-code-analysis, code-visualization

As the title suggests, I'm hoping for a static code visualization tool that can support any language.

I'm hoping there is some tool which can be given some information about the language, and generate a graph (I believe it's called "control flow graph" - a graph of which function calls which)

For the language I have in mind, for example, it seems relatively easy, since the language isn't very complex, and I can think of nothing I'm familiar with from languages such as C/C++ that would make it particularly difficult to analyze said language.

Comment: Which language do you want to visualize?

Comment: @DoubleM in my specific case, JASS. Not the kind of language that would have a code visualization tool made for it, which is why I'm looking for something which can accept something such as a parser for bison/yacc, which I do have.

Comment: You won't find a tool that will magically recognize and parse any random language. To understand a language's syntax, every tool needs a formally defined grammar to work with. From there, you can analyze and extract function definitions/calls and build a dependency graph. Many languages will require you to maintain a symbol table as well to resolve variable types etc. Check my revised answer for projects to get started.

Comment: @DoubleM I don't expect any "magic", that's why I said "given some infromation about the language", by which I meant something like a yacc parser, which I have

Comment: Ahh alright. Well if you have a parser or use the one suggested below, you can build a graph and visualize it with one of the many tools out there. I'm not aware of any specific `JASS` tool that would be ready off the shelf, but it should be an easy enough task to accomplish in half a day combining 2 more generic tools.

Answer (score 1):

*divine* statically analyzes and visualizes your code base. You may link a git repo or upload code directly. At the current beta state, `Java` binaries are supported. It will be expanded to also support languages such as `JavaScript`, `C`, `C++`, `C#`, `Swift`, `Objective-C` and `PHP`. Visualizations are interactive and you may follow the control flow in a tangle-free hive plot.

https://divine.engineering/for-engineers#code

Single projects are free.

*Disclaimer: I am directly affiliated with this product.*

---

**Edit** Here are tools specifically for `JASS`.

This one will give you function definitions and calls. It would be an easy task to assemble a call graph from it and visualize it using e.g. [Treeviz](http://www.randelshofer.ch/treeviz/) or [d3](https://d3js.org).
https://github.com/jfhs/php-jass-parser

This one is a bit more abstract, but might be helpful as well:
https://github.com/lep/jassjass

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't gogling parsers, didn't occur to me to look for parsers and try to use their output